# php strip non currency characters from string

Tags: php, regex

I have this string

```
From: £5.95 (per linear metre)
```

I want only the `£5.95` to remain.

I know this is done with preg_replace but how?

```
$string = "From: £5.95 (per linear metre)";
    echo preg_replace("", "", $string);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9.£]/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $str = "From: £5.95 (per linear metre)";
    preg_match_all("/From:\s(.*\d+)/", $str, $matches);
    echo $matches[1][0];

?>
```